# Spark - how to check if dates are not consecutive

Tags: python, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with `start_time` (timestamp), `ev_date`(in int) columns. I'm trying to figure out if the date in these two columns are consecutive. I only need to compare if the date is consecutive within each individual column. I'm thinking of using `lag` function but not sure how to implement it. How can I find out the missing dates? Many thanks.

Input:

```
ev_date |  start_time
---------------------
20220301| 2022-02-28 10:09:21.356782917
20220301| 2022-02-28 03:09:21.756982919
20220302| 2022-03-01 03:09:21.756982919
20220303| 2022-03-02 03:09:21.756982919
20220305| 2022-03-02 03:09:21.756982919 --ev_date is not right here as 20020304 is missing 
20220306| 2022-03-06 03:09:21.756982919 --start_time is not right as it jumped from 03-02 to 03-06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a new column with the difference and then if filter for where the diff is bigger than 1 day. something like (python but similar for scala - not sure which lang you need from the tags)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df1= df.withColumn("diff", datediff(df.ev_date, lag(df.ev_date, 1)
    .over(Window.partitionBy("some other column")
    .orderBy("ev_date")‌​)))
df1.filter(df1.diff > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks but could you explain a bit more what to do if there are no other columns to partitionBy? I hope to compare every row instead of a group of rows.

Comment: you need to create a window that will group every 2 rows (that's the lag) but the window function needs a partition by you can adda synthetic column that will be equal for all rows (.withColumn("fake", lit(1)) and then partition by it